# ¿Por qué no funciona el filtrado de un array JSON?

Tags: jquery

Tengo este código que lista los productos con un array JSON que traigo con Php usando AJAX:

```js
function listar(){
 
    tipofiltro="todos";
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/includes/php/filtroP.php",
            data: { "tf": tipofiltro},
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(data){
 
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 
                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].idproducto + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].marca + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].categoria + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].precio + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>";
                $(newRow).appendTo("#resultado");
 
 
 
            }
 
 
 
        };
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Entonces hago:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
listar();
 
 });
```

y aparecen todos los registros..
Pero quiero filtrar los datos, pero utilizando console.log el array JSON no llega, aparece undefined :

```js
$("#nombre").keyup(function() {
 
        var nombreBusqueda=$("#nombre").val();
         alert(nombreBusqueda);
            filtrado=data.filter(function (v){
 
                return v.nombre ^= nombreBusqueda;
 
            });
            console.log(filtrado.nombre)
            });
 
        }
 
        });
```

Me sugieren usar grep?

Comment: obviamente tenes razon..voy a editar la manera en que pregunto..gracias

Answer (score 0):

Con el siguiente codigo con el JSON dentro de una variable global funciona(borra la tabla y muestra los registros que coinciden), lo que no se es como hacer la busqueda caracter por caracter, y evaluar si el nobre de producto contiene la cadena buscada, es decir lo que hace like con los comodines de mysql.

```js
var content;
$(document).ready(function() {
listar();
var nombreBusqueda;

 $("#nombre").keyup(function() {
            
        nombreBusqueda=$("#nombre").val();
            filtrar(nombreBusqueda)
});
 });  

function filtrar(dato){
       var filtrado = content.filter(function (a) {
                return a.nombre === dato;
            });
            console.log(filtrado);
            for (var i = 0; i < filtrado.length; i++) {
          
                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].idproducto + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].marca + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].categoria + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].precio + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>";
                $("#resultado").empty();    
                $(newRow).appendTo("#resultado");                 
      

} 
 
  
};
```